# Evento teclado não funciona Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber porque este evento não funciona com algumas teclas. A tecla que desejo é a `seta para baixo (40)`, mas esta não funciona. Já as teclas `Enter (13)` e as `letras e números` funcionam normalmente. Já removi todo o código Jquery, e nada.

```
$('input[name=buscar]').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if(e.which == 40) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o evento `keydown` neste caso, porque o evento `keypress` não será disparado por teclas que não são "imprimíveis", como as setas do teclado, por exemplo.

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except that
>   **modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger**
>   **keydown events but not keypress events**. Other differences between the
>   two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

**Notas**

- O evento `keydown` pode ser utilizado para capturar as teclas `Shift`,
  `ESC` e `Delete`
- O evento `keypress` na verdade pode capturar as setas do teclado em alguns browsers, mas o `keydown` é mais confiável para este cenário, conforme indica a própria documentação
- Você deve utilizar as propriedades `.ctrlKey` , `.altKey` e
  `.shiftKey` do objeto event para verificar se as teclas `ctrl`, `alt`
  e `shift` foram disparadas

Código funcionando com `keydown`

```js
$('input[name=buscar]').keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if(e.which == 40) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="buscar" />
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys
https://api.jquery.com/keypress/